# Are identical things spatially clustered?

Tags: clustering, spatial

I'm new to working with spatial data, but I am working with a dataset of discrete plant genotypes sampled along a 1-d transect of 30 sampling points, and I would like to quantify the extent to which identical genotypes cluster together. I would then compare observed values to values for simulated populations.

What would be an appropriate measure for this?

My first crude attempt was to divide the mean distance between pairs of non-identical by the mean distance between pairs of identical genotypes. This seems unsatisfactory because it does not account for the absolute number of identical and non-identical pairs, which inflates the variance. My next thought was to calculate the covariance between pairwise identity and distance, but I don't think this behaves as I would expect. For example, if I design a transect to be as clustered as possible I expect this correlation to approach -1, which it only sort of does.

```
# Function to calculate the decay of pairwisw identity with distance
identity_vs_distance <- function(genotypes, positions){
  geno_pairs <- combn(genotypes, 2)
  geno_ix <- geno_pairs[1, ] == geno_pairs[2, ]
  dist_pairs <- combn(positions, 2)
  dist_pairs <- abs(dist_pairs[1, ] - dist_pairs[2, ])
  
  return(cor(geno_ix, dist_pairs, use='p'))
}

# Fictional data
genotypes <- rep(letters[1:3], each = 5)
positions <- 1:15

identity_vs_distance(genotypes, positions)
# -0.6813851
```

This feels like it ought to be simple, and something that should have an answer from ecology, physics or information theory, but I don't know enough about those fields to know what to look for. Measures of spatial autocorrelation seem to focus on continuous data. Conversely, measures of spatial entropy seem to deal with distance as measure discrete of how many neighbours you have (I'll admit I got pretty lost in this literature quite fast).